# How I can sort my results based on the order that sets the user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sorting, optimization

In my database I have many columns that will summarize in:

- Code input
- Amount 1
- Amount 2
- Code Phase
- Code Sector
- Code Group

Take an example of the rows that I have:

```
+--------------+----------+----------+-------+--------+-------+
|  code_input  | amount_1 | amount_2 | phase | sector | group |
+--------------+----------+----------+-------+--------+-------+
| 0171090150   | 22       | 14       | 09    | 90     |    10 |
| 0258212527   | 12       | 99       | 08    | 30     |    20 |
| 0359700504   | 30       | 10       | 09    | 20     |    20 |
+--------------+----------+----------+-------+--------+-------+
```

The user has a place in which he can decide who goes first, second, third and fourth. So, he can decide if the code_phase is first, second cod_sector, third code_group, finally the code_input. Or the user can play with that order (cod_sector first, code_phase second, etc).

In my database, inputs are those amounts recorded. Therefore, if a sector includes 2 inputs, the total of this sector is the sum of these two inputs.

Example of result with one order:

```
# => Order: Phase, Sector, Group, Input
- Phase 09                52  24
  - Sector 90             22  14
    - Group 10            22  14
      - Input 0171090150  22  14

  - Sector 20             30  10
    - Group 20            30  10
      - Input 0359700504  30  10

- Phase 08                12  99
  - Sector 30             12  99
    - Group 20            12  99
      - Input 0258212527  12  99
```

I use Ruby on Rails and I have a code of 3579 lines for all combinations that users can put. But it is a code that is not maintainable, cumbersome and sometimes I get confused myself where there may be a mistake.

So, I wonder if any of you can help me know if there is any gem that can help me; may not do the whole order; but help me greatly to optimize my code Or if you recommend a method or algorithm that can make this order.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Why can't you use an `ORDER BY phase, sector, group, input` or `ORDER BY input, phase, ...` and let the database deal with it? You'd just need to store the ORDER BY string somewhere.

Comment: @muistooshort Something like: `SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY [insert_order] ??`

Comment: Pretty much. Store or build the ORDER BY somewhere and say things like `Model.where(...).order(your_column_list_string)`.